# How can I make PowerShell wait until a command is complete before proceeding?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm using the following line to uninstall office 2007 based on its Product ID

```
Start-Process C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/uninstall {90120000-0030-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}"
```

I'd like to force a reboot after the uninstall is complete however using -Wait or piping the results to Out-Null don't wait until the uninstall is complete before processing the next line which is a restart.  I've also tried using cmd to uninstall but with the same result.

```
cmd /c "msiexec.exe /uninstall {90120000-0030-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}"
```

Is there any way to force powershell to wait until the uninstall is complete before processing the Restart-Computer command?  I was thinking possibly writing something that detects when the setup.exe process stops before proceeding to the restart?

Comment: Have you tried `Start-Process -Wait`?

Comment: Could you use msiexec's `/forcerestart` option in this case?

Comment: Matt - That did the trick, using `cmd /c "msiexec.exe /uninstall {{90120000-0030-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE} /forcerestart"`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Start-Process has a wait parameter:

```
Start-Process C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/uninstall {90120000-0030-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}" -wait
```

The solution to restart after an `misexec.exe` uninstallation is to add the `/forcerestart` parameter to the  msiexec call instead of trying to restart in powershell (Credits to Matt):

```
Start-Process C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe -ArgumentList @("/uninstall {90120000-0030-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}", "/forcerestart")
```

Comment: In case you need to use a filename instead of a GUID and that filename has spaces in it:  `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList '/i "C:\Temp\SQLSysClrTypes 15.0.2000.5.msi" /qr' -NoNewWindow -Wait`

Comment: The "-wait" is not always functional; Sometime sthe job ignore the wait, like in invoke-command -scriptblock. - NoT sure why, yet...

Answer (score 14):

The simplest workaround: pipe the result. This will force a wait until the process is finished.

No need for `start-process` or `cmd`.

You could pipe to `out-default`, `out-file`, `out-null` or `out-host`, depending on how you want to handle the output. (If you don't care about the output, simply use `out-null`.)

```
& msiexec.exe /uninstall "{90120000-0030-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}" | Out-Null
```

Comment: This should be the answer. However. I would pipe to `Write-Verbose` so that you can inspect the output if so required.

Comment: +1 for this answer althought the current accepted answer (Start-Process) is more explicit in intention. I like this solution though so I still used it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for this is to actually get the Office Removal Tool from Microsoft and extract the VBS script from it. Run that in a Start-Process with the -wait argument, and reboot afterwards. It will not only attempt to gracefully remove Office with msiexec as you are doing, it will also go back and clean up any straggling files or registry entries in case the application is corrupt and will not uninstall nicely.