# How can I install CMake with PowerShell? (automatic installation)

Tags: windows, powershell, cmake

I want to install CMake without any interaction. I tried [this script](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WebKitDev/0.1.6/Content/Functions%5CInstall-CMake.ps1), but there's no `Install-FromMsi` on my PowerShell.

Is there a fix for that or an easier way to install CMake and put it into the PowerShell path just with scripts?

PS: how to call `Install-CMake` with parameters?

**UPDATE:**

I followed https://silentinstallhq.com/cmake-silent-install-how-to-guide/ and tried

```
Write-Host "Installing Cmake..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
$exePath = "$env:TEMP\cmake.exe"

Write-Host "Downloading..."
(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.24.0/cmake-3.24.0-windows-x86_64.msi', $exePath)

Write-Host "Installing..."
MsiExec.exe /i $exePath ADD_CMAKE_TO_PATH=User /qn
```

but my Windows does not recognize the command `MsiExec.exe`

I changed to

```
Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList "/i $exePath ADD_CMAKE_TO_PATH=User /qn"

cmake --version
```

It looks like it installs but `cmake --version` says that `cmake` is not a command in PowerShell, so either it's not installing or not putting into `PATH`.

Comment: `Install-FromMsi` is included with the module.  Install the module and then try running `Install-CMake`  https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WebKitDev/0.4.0

Comment: @Daniel is it possible to extract the Install-FromMsi alone?

Comment: Just as you were probably doing with `Install-CMake`, you can copy and paste the function from the site https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WebKitDev/0.4.0/Content/Functions%5CInstall-FromMsi.ps1

Comment: @Daniel how did you see the functions? I need also ` Invoke-WebFileRequest` but don't know how to find them

Comment: I think too much functions are required for installing cmake with this method. Isn't there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ADD_CMAKE_TO_PATH=User` does what it should do, but there are two problems in your case:

1. You have to wait until [`msiexec.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec) finishes. To do that, either pipe the result of the direct invocation to somewhere:

   ```
   msiexec.exe /i $exePath ADD_CMAKE_TO_PATH=User /qn | Out-Null
   ```

   Or use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) with the `-Wait` parameter (which you already did):

   ```
   Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/i $exePath ADD_CMAKE_TO_PATH=User /qn" -Wait
   ```

   You can read more about that in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26492328/11942268).
2. When you update the environment variables of the `Machine` or `User` scope, existing processes will not inherit them into their existing `Process` scope. That's why your already running PowerShell process still does not know `cmake` after its installation. You can read more about that in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63006323/11942268).

   You either have to start a *really* new PowerShell process (see above linked Q&A) or you have to reimport the environement variables of the `Machine` and `User` scope into your `Process` scope:

   ```
   foreach($level in "Machine","User") {
      [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables($level).GetEnumerator() | % {
         # For Path variables, append the new values, if they're not already in there
         if($_.Name -match 'Path$') { 
            $_.Value = ($((Get-Content "Env:$($_.Name)") + ";$($_.Value)") -split ';' | Select -unique) -join ';'
         }
         $_
      } | Set-Content -Path { "Env:$($_.Name)" }
   }
   ```

   This code is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22670892/11942268).

   After that, `cmake --version` and `Get-Command cmake` will work.

---

Side notes:

- If `Start-Process` can find `msiexec.exe`, then the direct invocation should also work. Maybe you just had a typo, when trying that.
- A more *PowerShelly* way to download a file is:

  ```
  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.24.0/cmake-3.24.0-windows-x86_64.msi -UseBasicParsing -OutFile $exePath
  ```