# How can I install git (with bash on PowerShell) on PowerShell?

Tags: windows, git, powershell

https://gitforwindows.org/ has an option to put bash into PowerShell. I need that so no installing WSL and etc. I need to install git unattended, that is, with command line only. Existing tutorials like [this](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/powershell/powershell-install-git/) only launch the installer using PowerShell, but I have to use the mouse to install stuff.

So, how can I install git, with bash on PowerShell, using PowerShell?

**UPDATE:**

I tried

```
Write-Host "Installing Git for windows..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
$exePath = "$env:TEMP\git.msi"

Write-Host "Downloading..."
(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.37.1.windows.1/Git-2.37.1-64-bit.exe', $exePath)

Write-Host "Installing..."
Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '$exePath /NORESTART /NOCANCEL /SP- /CLOSEAPPLICATIONS /RESTARTAPPLICATIONS /COMPONENTS="icons,ext\reg\shellhere,assoc,assoc_sh" /LOG="C:git-for-windows.log"'

git --version
bash
```

but it gets stuck on "Installing..." and does not print any other outputs.

Comment: Why are you saving the download as an msi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/) does not get released as an MSI package. And you cannot convert a regular executable into an MSI package just by renaming it. You do not need `msiexec.exe` at all. The installer itself has already paramaters to perform a silent installation. Just execute it as is:

   ```
   $exePath = "$env:TEMP\git.exe"
   Start-Process $exePath -Wait -ArgumentList '/NORESTART /NOCANCEL /SP- /CLOSEAPPLICATIONS /RESTARTAPPLICATIONS /COMPONENTS="icons,ext\reg\shellhere,assoc,assoc_sh" /LOG="C:\git-for-windows.log"'
   ```

   But: This will sill launch a GUI. So you have to add more parameters to make the installation really silent. Further reading:

   - [Git: Silent or Unattended Installation](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Silent-or-Unattended-Installation)
   - [Git For Windows Silent Install Silent Arguments](https://superuser.com/q/944576/1077440)

   TL;DR: Also add `/VERYSILENT` and you might want to use `/LOADINF` to customize some settings.
2. After the successful installation, you will face the same problem, you already did in your similar question, I just [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73316145/11942268). TL;DR:

   The environment variables in your current `Process` scope are not updated automatically. Update them manually by:

   > ```
   > foreach($level in "Machine","User") {
   >    [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables($level).GetEnumerator() | % {
   >       # For Path variables, append the new values, if they're not already in there
   >       if($_.Name -match 'Path$') { 
   >          $_.Value = ($((Get-Content "Env:$($_.Name)") + ";$($_.Value)") -split ';' | Select -unique) -join ';'
   >       }
   >       $_
   >    } | Set-Content -Path { "Env:$($_.Name)" }
   > }
   > ```
   >
   > This code is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22670892/11942268).

   After that, `git --version` and `Get-Command git` will work.

---

Full script:

```
$exePath = "$env:TEMP\git.exe"

# Download git installer
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.37.1.windows.1/Git-2.37.1-64-bit.exe -UseBasicParsing -OutFile $exePath

# Execute git installer
Start-Process $exePath -ArgumentList '/VERYSILENT /NORESTART /NOCANCEL /SP- /CLOSEAPPLICATIONS /RESTARTAPPLICATIONS /COMPONENTS="icons,ext\reg\shellhere,assoc,assoc_sh"' -Wait

# Optional: For bash.exe, add 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin' to PATH
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', "$([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'Machine'));C:\Program Files\Git\bin", 'Machine')

# Make new environment variables available in the current PowerShell session:
foreach($level in "Machine","User") {
   [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables($level).GetEnumerator() | % {
      # For Path variables, append the new values, if they're not already in there
      if($_.Name -match 'Path$') { 
         $_.Value = ($((Get-Content "Env:$($_.Name)") + ";$($_.Value)") -split ';' | Select -unique) -join ';'
      }
      $_
   } | Set-Content -Path { "Env:$($_.Name)" }
}

# Work with git
git --version
bash
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# Make new environment variables available in the current PowerShell session:
function reload {
   foreach($level in "Machine","User") {
      [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables($level).GetEnumerator() | % {
         # For Path variables, append the new values, if they're not already in there
         if($_.Name -match 'Path$') { 
            $_.Value = ($((Get-Content "Env:$($_.Name)") + ";$($_.Value)") -split ';' | Select -unique) -join ';'
         }
         $_
      } | Set-Content -Path { "Env:$($_.Name)" }
   }
}
Write-Host "Installing git..." -ForegroundColor Cyan

$exePath = "$env:TEMP\git.exe"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.37.1.windows.1/Git-2.37.1-64-bit.exe -UseBasicParsing -OutFile $exePath

Start-Process $exePath -ArgumentList '/VERYSILENT /NORESTART /NOCANCEL /SP- /CLOSEAPPLICATIONS /RESTARTAPPLICATIONS /COMPONENTS="icons,ext\reg\shellhere,assoc,assoc_sh"' -Wait

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', "$([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'Machine'));C:\Program Files\Git\bin", 'Machine')

reload

git --version
bash --version
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the exact answer for your question.

Since you do not prefer something as heavy as WSL, I have a good alternative for your purpose that also promises native windows filesystem support. Use MSYS2 instead of gitbash. This is far better and git-bash is originally based on MSYS2

1. Download the prefered package of [MSYS2](https://github.com/msys2/msys2-installer/releases/).
2. If you downloaded the GUI installer, install it via CLI with
   `.\msys2-x86_64-latest.exe in --confirm-command --accept-messages --root C:/msys64`

Or if you had downloaded the self extracting archive, install it using
`.\msys2-base-x86_64-latest.sfx.exe -y -oC:\`

3. Lauch MSYS2, then update the packages list with `pacman -Syu`.
4. Install git with `pacman -S git`

You will eventually come to love it.
Note that some keyboard shortcuts you are used to in linux may not work example Ctrl+Shift+v for pasting is not supported and Windows uses Shift+Insert

[Credits](https://medium.com/@saml/setting-up-a-light-weight-linux-like-non-wsl-terminal-environment-on-windows-59a583c958ed)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, check if the  `/LOG="C:git-for-windows.log"` part of your command has a typo

```
 /LOG="C:\git-for-windows.log"
        ^^^ 
        (\ was missing)
```

That way, you can try again, and monitor `C:\git-for-windows.log` for logs.

Also, make sure you have the right to write directly under `C:\`.
A `/LOG="$env:userprofile\git-for-windows.log"` might be safer.

Answer (score 1):

Run the git install once with the `SAVEINF` parameter, choosing all the options that you'd like to install in the installation UI:

```
.\Git-2.37.1-64-bit.exe /SAVEINF="c:\temp\git-install.inf"
```

This will create an install configuration file, which you can use to do a silent install of git using powershell:

```
$uri = 'https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.37.1.windows.1/Git-2.37.1-64-bit.exe'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -OutFile git-install.exe
.\git-install.exe /LOADINF="c:\temp\git-install.inf" /VERYSILENT
```

This will spawn a background process and exit immediately. You can wait for it to complete like this:

```
while (Get-Process *git-install*) { sleep -seconds 5 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now its very easy to use git terminal on PowerShell just use following commands

First, Set execution policy as remotesigned.
Run powershell as Administrator and run below command

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

To install the git on powershell

```
Install-Module posh-git -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

To import the git module

```
Import-Module posh-git
```

To load profile by default on powershell startup

```
Add-PoshGitToProfile -AllHosts​​​​​​​
```